# Angular ssr keeps waiting for the file that does not exist

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have angular universal app and when I run the app with ssr and if there is any image does not exist it keeps wating for the report [image]

but when I run without ssr it shows image not found which is okay so is there any way to handle this is ssr mode.
This is the code to handle the request in

> server.ts

```
 server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, {
      req,
      providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }],
    });
  });
```